# MariaDB version not recognised

Tags: mysql, installation

Getting the following error on a CentOS 9 server:

> You cannot install because WordPress 6.0 requires MySQL version 5.0 or higher. You are running version .

So it doesn't appear to be picking up the server version, which is MariaDB 10.5

I know thats working as I've created a basic PHP script to test the database connection.

I can connect to database remotely, just PHP/WordPress not picking up the version.

Also I know 6.0 is not the latest version, but I changed version whilst debugging.

Comment: Cross-posted from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76465194/wordpress-install-on-new-server-not-recognising-mariadb-version.

Comment: Can you edit wp-admin/install.php to `echo 'db_server_info=' . $wpdb->db_server_info();` somewhere around line 230 where it's doing the version check? It would be useful to see that string.

Comment: Output from your code @Rup is db_server_info=10.5.16-MariaDB

Comment: Then it should have worked :-( Starting with that string, $wpdb->db_version() = "10.5.16" - whereas it looks like that's being echoed out as empty for you - and version_compare() works for me.

Comment: `sudo yum install pcre2` to resolve a problem with preg_match, which would have been the problem `$wpdb->db_version()` not returning... finally some progress and problem solved.

Comment: Congrats! That might be worth posting as an answer here or on SO too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As discussed in comments, the problem was a missing prce2 package which meant preg_match(), used by $wpdb->db_version() to parse the MySQL version number out of SELECT VERSION(), didn't work. Solved by

```sh
sudo yum install pcre2
```