# WordPress install on new server not recognising MariaDB version

Tags: php, mysql

Getting the following error on A CentOS server:

> You cannot install because WordPress 6.0 requires MySQL version 5.0 or higher. You are running version .

So it doesn't appear to be picking up the server version, which is MariaDB 10.5

I know thats working as I've created a basic PHP script to test the database connection.

I can connect to database remotely, just PHP/WordPress not picking up the version.

Comment: This is strange, for two reasons. (1) You seem to be trying to install WordPress 6.0, and the current version is 6.2.2 as of June 2023.   (2) MariaDB 10.5 definitely works.  Is it possible your installation is pointing to some other MariaDB / MySQL version? You probably should revisit your server configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, originally I was installing 6.2.2 but during the debug process I tried a different version on the off chance it was related to the WordPress version. Its a new server, so no other versions of MariaDB running.

Comment: Try issuing the `SELECT VERSION()` query when you connect to MariaDB from some other code. That's how WordPress finds out the version.  And double check you've completed [all the installation steps](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mariadb-on-ubuntu-20-04). If this were my brand-new VM I'd delete it and start over.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MariaDB version not recognised](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/416723/mariadb-version-not-recognised)